# What it the group of transformation that leaves the commutator of two matrices invariant?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let's consider the space V of pairs of N*N traceless hermitian matrices. For any pair {A,B} of matrices, we can associate the commutator [A,B]=AB-BA .

Let's define the group G as the group of all transformations $V \to V$ that preserves the commutator. That is, for any $g \in G$, and any pair $\{A,B\} \in V$, we have

$$ [A_g , B_g ] = [A,B]$$

where $\{A_g, B_g\} = g(\{A,B\})$

What is this group G? (What is it's dimension? Does it have a well-known name?)

Here is my attempt at answering the question:

We can decompose A and B into a complete basis of hermitian traceless matrices $A= a_n T^n$, $B = b_n T^n$, where $Tr(T_n)=0$ and $Tr(T_n T_m)= \delta_{n m}$, such that $a_n=Tr(T_n A)$.

At the infinitesimal level, I believe then that the  transformations are given by

$$
a_n \to a_n + \partial_{b_n} Tr(f(A,B)), \quad
b_n \to b_n - \partial_{a_n} Tr(f(A,B))
$$

Where f(A,B) is an arbitrary polynomial in the matrices A and B.

If this is true, I believe that $N^2-1$ independent traces can be formed using these two matrices, such that this group would be of dimension $N^2-1$.

Is this correct? And if yes, what group does it correspond to?

I hope the problem is well-defined enough and I thank you for your help!

Comment: What set does this group act on, and what is the action?

Comment: I am searching for the group that acts on the set {$a_n$,$b_n$} as $\{a_n, b_n\} \to  \{f_n(\{a_k,b_k\}),g_n(\{a_k,b_k\})\}$, where $f_n$ and $g_n$ are any functions that leave the commutator invariant.

Comment: You don't understand my question. A [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) has a group and a space it acts on. In this case, does it act on the space of pairs of hermitian matrices? Do you want each transformation to be polynomial in the entries of the matrices? It's hard to understand what you're saying.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Indeed, it is the space of pairs of traceless hermitian matrices. I edited the question to make it clearer. Hopefully it answers your comment. Thanks!

Comment: You really want *all* transformations $V \rightarrow V$ which preserve the commutator? Not just, say, the ones that are (also) linear?